# How to calculate weight average using dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I have two measures in my model(Velocity, Carry Over). I would like to calculate the weight of this measures and create a new measure using the below logic.

```
If  Velocity >85 then set Score=5 
else If  Velocity is >70 and <85 set score=3 
else If  Velocity <70 then set score=1
   then multiply resulted score by 60%(weight-0.6) then store the Result 1.

If Carry Over <10 then set Score=5
else If Carry Over is > 10 and <20 then set Score=3
else If Carry Over is > 20 then set Score=1
    
    Then multiply resulted Score by 40%(weight-0.4) and store the Result 2.
    

then Desired value Final Measure =Result 1+ Result 2
```

I have tried to write a dax but I am not sure how can i store it in variable for multiple expressions and get one final measure.

```
Score1 = 
IF(
    'Sprints'[Velocity %] > 85,
    "5",
    IF(
        'Sprints'[Velocity %] < 85 && 'Sprints'[Velocity %] >70,
        "3",
        If('Sprints'[Velocity %] < 70,"1"
    )))
```

I am new bae to dax and powerbi..I appreciate the help.

Comment: What have you tried?  Start here for using DAX variables for multi-stage calculations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/dax-variables

Comment: I have did the first expression check but I was not able to to transcendence to the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
    Measure = 
    VAR Velocity =
    IF (
       'Sprints'[velocity %] > 85,
       5,
        IF (
           'Sprints'[Velocity %] < 85
              && 'Sprints'[Velocity %] > 70,
            3,
        IF ( 'Sprints'[Velocity %] < 70, 1 )
       )
     )
   VAR Carryover =
   IF (
       'Sprints'[Carry Over] < 10,
        5,
        IF (
           'Sprints'[Carry Over] > 10
             && 'Sprints'[Carry Over] < 20,
            3,
          IF ( 'Sprints'[Velocity %] > 20, 1 )
           )
         )
   VAR Res1 = 0.6 * Velocity
   VAR Res2 = 0.4 * Carryover
   RETURN
       ( Res1 + Res2 )
```